# Windows 11 Microsoft store won't open

Tags: windows-11, windows-update, microsoft-store

I am using Windows 11. Recently I was trying to download an app from the Microsoft store, but the store was stuck on the [loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D9aC.png).

So, after searching online for a fix, I tried to [reset the Microsoft store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqfXk.png) and restart my PC. Then when I checked for potential Windows updates in settings, the buttons in the update tab were [grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEjrZ.png).

I also noticed that when I try to fix the problem using `CMD`, I get Windows Defender Error code: 0x80029c4a.

This problem has annoyed me for two weeks now, so I would appreciate the help, since I need to use the Microsoft store.

Comment: `when I try to fix the problem using CMD` what did you do?

Comment: Make sure you are using a Microsoft Account and that your Microsoft Account is logged in.  Run DISM / SFC and test  ....     (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @Bravo. I meant when I tried to reset windows update through Command prompt.

Comment: @John SFC first, DISM only if needed: https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/161345-what-correct-order-dism-sfc-commands-fix-problems.html#post1976657

Comment: No. You need to run DISM first and then SFC to correct any remaining errors after DISM. This is well documented.   @OP  also run the update troubleshooter.   https://wureset.com/

Comment: @John. I did step 1 and step 2. When i tried step 3 i got this: [Error: 87
DISM doesn't recognize the command-line option "(4)".
For more information, refer to the help by running DISM.exe /?.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log]

Comment: @Omar - Update your questions to provide the exact command you issued. Unformatted comments make it impossible to determine what you actually ran

Comment: @Omar "*when I tried to reset windows update through Command prompt*" - yes, but WHAT did you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i tried step 3 i got this: [Error: 87 DISM doesn't recognize the
> command-line option

**(1)** Since the initial repairs failed, you need to try a Windows 11 Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

> Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Download.  Run the downloaded file  (double click
> on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB
> Key. Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.   Proceed
> normally answering the prompts.  The default Keep prompt is to Keep
> Everything.

**(2)** If Repair Install / Keep Everything fails to resolve the problem, then either (1) there is Windows User Profile damage or (2) more serious Operating System damage.

In either case, back everything up, and do a fresh install of Windows 11. Restore Apps and Data once running correctly